# Verify if POJO data class was mapped correctly

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am using a POJO data class with GSON to parse the data which is being called from the Firestore database.

For example, I have a POJO class with few non-nullable, and nullable values like userID

```
data class Users(id:String="", userID:String="" ...)
```

I am then using GSON to parse the JSON data to object for that class

```
 val gson = Gson()
 val jsonObjects = gson.toJson(querySnapshot.data)
 val parseData = gson.fromJson(jsonObjects,Users::class.java)
```

My question is if someone uploads data in the database and forgets to add the userID (i.e. it is null), is there a way I can check if the User data class is valid when being parsed?

I am using a check like if(userID == ""){return false} . But as the number of non-nullable fields grows it gets tedious and there must be a better way to check this.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is if someone uploads data in the database and forgets to add the userID (i.e. it is null), is there a way I can check if the User data class is valid when being parsed?

If you don't want to have null values at all, why would you then let the user the possibility to provide incomplete data? The simplest solution would be to restrict the data that is added to the database. How? Simply by creating some constraints. For example, your users cannot get access to a feature in your app if they do not fill in all the **required** fields. That's an operation that is widely used.

If you already have null values, then checking against nullity is a solution you can go ahead with. In Kotlin, [null safety](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html) can be handled in many ways, either by [checking for null in conditions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#checking-for-null-in-conditions), using [safe calls](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#safe-calls), [elvis operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#elvis-operator) or even using [the !! operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#the-operator).

Comment: Yes that check is in place, however as this is a multi platform application, and for example the web dev forgot to add this check and the database get updated with a null value I want to handle the exception well. 
Yes null checks are in place in the app with null conditions, but I wish to know if the Data object is valid. If its not valid performing other operations is worthless.

Comment: As explained in the question I have if(userID == ""){return false} in place to check if its null/empty. Just wanted to know if there is a more elegant solution if we have to check multiple fields.

Comment: When you have to deal with null values in your documents, then you should always consider checking against nullity. As far as I know, something better doesn't yet exist which can be considered better than the Kotlin programming language already provides.

Comment: Thankyou for your information, although a valid and reasonable answer, I think it still hasn't made my doubt clear. I'm still researching this thing out, will give out an upvote but will withhold an accepted answer till I figure this one out. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, lyncx. If I can help you with other information, just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `extension` method of Kotlin is an accepted approach.

Let me show a demo, I assume the class `User` looks like this:

```
data class User(
    val id: String,
    val userId: String?  // nullable
)
```

Create a extension method `User.isValid()` to verify the fields you want.

```
fun User.isValid() = when {
    userId.isNullOrEmpty() -> false
    else -> true
}
```

The method `isNullOrEmpty()` is in stdlib of Kotlin. I test the code, it works fine.

```
    val user1 = User("id 001", null)
    val user2 = User("id 002", "userId 001")
    println(user1.isValid()) //==> print false
    println(user2.isValid()) //==> print true
```

**Now, back to your worry point:**

> ...But as the number of non nullable fields grow it gets tedious

I changed the class `User`

```
data class User(
    val id: String,
    val userId: String?,
    val email: String?,
    val name: String?
)
```

it means that when the fields of `userId`, `email`, `name`, any of them is null, the `User` is invalid.
Just add conditions in extention method, like this:

```
fun User.isValid() = when {
    userId.isNullOrEmpty()
            || email.isNullOrEmpty()
            || name.isNullOrEmpty() -> false
    
    else -> true
}
```

We just need to maintain the method of `isValid`.

**conclusion**

1. Kotlin Extension Method can be used in your case.
2. It's better don't use `id=""`, also can create an extension method for this empty string if need.

```
fun String.Companion.empty() = ""
data class User(
    val id: String,
    val userId: String? = String.empty()
    ...
)
```

3. All the extension methods can be placed in a class, like `UserExt.kt` for easy maintaining.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but Im trying to check on non nullable values. userID: String is non nullable. 
Also when parsing data from firebase I will require a default constructor for data class so I cannot initialise the data class as userID:String but will have to do something like userID:String = "".